# sizeof string array in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

I am confused about the sizeof string array in C++, I have the following string array:

```
static const char* namedButtonStr[] = {
        "GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON",
        "GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON",
        "GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON"
};
```

And to get the size of this array, the following code is used:

```
int size = int(sizeof(namedButtonStr)/sizeof(namedButtonStr[0]));
```

Where `sizeof(namedButtonStr)` is 12, `sizeof(namedButtonStr[0])` is 4, and the size of the array is 12/4 = 3.

My question is, why `sizeof(namedButtonStr)` is 12 and `sizeof(namedButtonStr[0])` is 4? My understanding is `sizeof(namedButtonStr)` is 3 and `sizeof(namedButtonStr[0])` is 17 ("GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON" has 17 characters).

Comment: If you're writing C++, why not write real C++, and use something like: `std::vector<std::string> namedButtons = {"GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON", "GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON", "GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON"};`. In this case, the number of strings is just `namedButtons.size()`.

Comment: `namedButtons` is an array of pointers, not an array of strings. Each element points to the first character of a string.

Comment: @Hi, I'm new to c++, I'm learning `OpenGL`, this code came from my teacher, there must be some reason he created the string array like that, can you explain it?

Comment: @Tom - You will be surprised at the amount of bad "teacher code" that shows up every day here.

Comment: what is actually created is an array of 3 string pointers, where each pointer points to a string.  The string(s) location is in the .rodata, so the actual strings cannot be changed.

Comment: @Tom this is a standard way to store a list of strings. Just bear in mind that the strings themselves are not in an array. The strings are in a separate data area (probably read-only) and this array contains some pointers telling where the strings can be found.   There are good reasons to do that, this code is fine.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: A `vector` of `strings` requires initialization by calling the `vector` and `string` constructors.  The array of `static const char *` is fixed and doesn't need to be initialized (the compilers usually place it verbatim into the read-only data section).  This is a popular idiom for embedded systems; to allow the constant data to reside elsewhere and access directly without any additional overhead.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The "GLUT*" strings are a pretty strong hint that this is most likely aimed at desktop systems (specifically, ones running GLUT).

Comment: [Closely related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26726367/179910).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`namedButtonStr[0]` is of type `const char*`, so its `sizeof` is the size of pointer, not the array it points to.

`namedButtonStr`, on the contrary, is an array, so its `sizeof` is the bytesize of the whole array, that is, `3 * sizeof(<one item in the array>)`.

---

Edit: By the way, this is a pretty standard idiom for determining array's size, you'll see it often.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, why `sizeof(namedButtonStr)` is 12 and `sizeof(namedButtonStr[0])` is 4? My understanding is `sizeof(namedButtonStr)` is 3 and `sizeof(namedButtonStr[0])` is 17 ("GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON" has 17 characters).

The `namedButtonStr` will contain 3 pointers. (In general, a C pointer is 4 bytes, this may change as 64 bit busses become common, along with 64 bit compilers.)

So, 3 pointers * 4 (bytes per pointer) = 12 bytes.

The `namedButtonStr[0]` refers to a single/first one of those 3 pointers, and as stated above, each pointer is 4 bytes.

The result is 12/4 = 3